# Dynamically resize overflow scrolling in a div without media queries

Tags: javascript, jquery, css, html

Just wondering if there is a "simpler" way to resize a scrollbar than just use media queries?

If I have to use media queries, then I have to adjust all the possible screen resolutions!

Code example!

```
@media only screen and (min-height: 700px)
and (max-height: 750px){
    #Container {
        height: 580px !important;
    }
}

@media only screen and (min-height: 750px)
and (max-height: 900px){
    #Container {
        height: 680px !important;
    }
}

@media only screen and (min-height: 900px) {
    #Container {
        height: 750px !important;
    }
}





#Container {
    max-width: 100% !important;
    width: auto !important;
    overflow: auto;

}
```

Comment: Why not simply use a percentage?

Comment: hmm then the scrollbar won't show up if I use percentage on the height

Comment: Can you make a fiddle? that would help with answers.